# & Statement in IF loop does not work

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I really dont know what I am doing wrong.

This code does not work in R Studio (I have tried multiple little changes but to no avail):

```
Data3$Rebound3<-0
for (i in 2:length(Data3)){
  if((Data3$etype[i] == 'SHOT') && (Data3$etype[i-1] == 'SHOT')){
    Data3$Rebound3[i]<-1}}
```

But these 2 codes work:

```
Data3$Rebound3<-0
for (i in 2:length(Data3)){
  if(Data3$etype[i] == 'SHOT'){
    Data3$Rebound3[i]<-1}}

Data3$Rebound3<-0
for (i in 2:length(Data3)){
  if(Data3$etype[i-1] == 'SHOT'){
    Data3$Rebound3[i]<-1}}
```

Thanks in Advance for Help!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ?  Please read the posting guidelines and supply a small, reproducible dataset.  I would also point out that you clearly have no idea what `list` variables are, as you're looping over the length of `Data3` but trying to access elements of `Data3$etype`, which won't have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without a `for` loop

```
 indx <- with(Data3, c(FALSE,etype[-1]=='SHOT' & etype[-nrow(Data3)]=='SHOT'))
 Data3$Rebound3 <- indx+0
 head(Data3)
 #           etype Rebound3
 #1           SHOT        0
 #2           SHOT        1
 #3 SOMETHING ELSE        0
 #4      SOMETHING        0
 #5      SOMETHING        0
 #6 SOMETHING ELSE        0
```

Regarding your code, the `2:length(Data3)` will be giving the `column` index instead of the `row` index (if I understand from your code).  I guess you want the `row` index.  Perhaps,

```
Data3$Rebound3<-0
for(i in 2:nrow(Data3)){
     if(Data3$etype[i] == 'SHOT' & Data3$etype[i-1] == 'SHOT'){
         Data3$Rebound3[i]<-1
     }
   }

Data3$Rebound3
#[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 Data3 <- data.frame(etype=sample(c('SHOT', 'SOMETHING', 'SOMETHING ELSE'),
                 20, replace=TRUE))
```